# Разные проходы по коллекции в С++

Tags: c++, контейнеры

недавно заинтересовался вопросом, на тему того, какие из различных методов проходов через коллекцию наиболее эффективные и производительные, да и вообще когда и в какой ситуации лучше применять тот или иной метод? За основу возьмем std::vector.

```
...
std::vector<std::string> cities;
std::string rostov = "Ростов";
std::string omsk = "Омск";
cities.push_back(rostov);
cities.push_back(omsk);
...
```

#### 1 Метод - самый примитивный

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++)
{
     std::cout << cities.at(i) << std::endl;
}
```

#### 2 Метод - range for

```
for (const auto& city : cities)
{
    std::cout << city << std::endl;
}
```

#### 3 Метод - iterators

```
for (auto it = cities.begin(); it != cities.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

#### 4 Метод - лямбды

```
std::for_each(cities.begin(), cities.end(), [] (std::string &city)
{  
    std::cout << city << std::endl;
});
```

Для примера был приведен вектор с двумя элементами, хотелось бы чтобы была затронут разговор про большого объема контейнеры. А также хотелось бы услышать про то какой из вариантов лучше и почему, если в теле цикла производить не просто вывод его элементов(можно было бы сделать так std::copy(...)), а производить какого-либо рода вычисления над элементами. Заранее спасибо...

Comment: _производить какого-либо рода вычисления над элементами_ - а вот тут поподробнее. Имхо, нужно разделить вопрос на два: проход по коллекции с изменением и без изменения элементов.

Comment: Как раз таки проход по коллекции с изменениями и без изменениями, дабы понять что для чего лучше предназначено. А также большого объема коллекция и маленького...

Comment: Вектор - коллекция очень особенная, и непоказательная, ибо допускает эффективный доступ по индексу. А вы ее "взяли за основу"...

Comment: Стоящий оптимизирующий компилятор сгенерирует идентичный код для всех четырёх случаев...  Но если позволительно использовать С++11, то я бы считал второй способ предпочтительным в силу его сладости... иначе — третий...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом методе не нужен доступ к элементу с проверкой  (`cities.at(i)`    ) лишнее, так как в цикле вы исключили выход за пределы границ.    Просто выводить нужно `cities[i]`, тогда он будет эффективным.

Эффективнее изначально не хранить лишные обьекты :

```
std::vector<std::string> cities;
cities.push_back("Ростов");
cities.push_back("Омск");
```

Второй вариант также эффективен, как и следующий вариант:

```
copy(cities.begin(), cities.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
```

Самый плохой вариант это четвертый, поскольку  `std::for_each` каждый раз вызывает лямбду и возвращает ее, котрая вам в принципе не нужна. И если вы пытаетесь пользоваться альгоритмом `std::for_each,` то сначала подумайте, нет ли более специализированного альгоритма типа того, что я привел?

Comment: "`std::for_each` каждый раз вызывает лямбду и возвращает ее, которая вам в принципе не нужна" - что это значит?

Comment: @AnT, вы сами прекрасно понимаете что я имел ввиду. Если я плохо изложил, то просто поправте.

Comment: Я честно *не понимаю*, что вы имели в виду. Вот именно "возвращает её" - что такое "её"? Лямбду? Но лямбду тут никто "каждый раз" не возвращает.

Comment: @AnT,  возвращаемое значение альгоритма  это  копия объекта функции  
 после того, как он будет применяться ко всем элементам в диапазоне.

Comment: Значит я вас неправильно понял. Я думал, что под "каждый раз" вы имели в виду "на каждой итерации". Так как "возвращения лямбды" на каждой итерации тут нет, считать это проблемой смысла нет: данная лямбда - это пустой объект и ее однократное (на цикл) возвращение на эффективность не повлияет.